# append function jquery with data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to retrieve data from a json file and append it to the html file. It almost works, but when I append, it appends "data.username" to the site rather than the data located at data.username. I made sure that the data name in the json matched the name in the code.

```
    <script>
        $.getJSON('package.json', function(data){
            var username = data.username;
            $(".list-group").append('<li>username</li>');
        });
    </script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try '+ username +'

```
 <script>
        $.getJSON('package.json', function(data){
            var username = data.username;
            $(".list-group").append('<li>'+username+'</li>');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat the html strings with your `username` variable. You can't stick a variable in the middle of a string literal.

```
$(".list-group").append('<li>' + username + '</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is use `alert(data.username)` to see what value is coming back and then change the code which looks incorrect to me `$(".list-group").append('<li>' + username + '</li>');`